# C# Unit Testing using webClient.UploadString

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I am using webClient.uploadString(uri,parameter) method.
It hits an url which returns a string. Whenever there is Bad request or other similar kind of errors, the server throws exception.

While Unit testing I need to compare the Response Status Code with some specific status codes.

The UploadString method only return string.

My query is:
**How can I get the Response Object from WebClient so that I can compare the status Code**?

Comment: When you make out of process calls that's no more a UnitTest. Apart from that it isn't clear for me what you're testing here.

Answer (score 1):

You can only determine the status code if the request fails:

```
try
{
    var client = new WebClient();
    client.DownloadString("...");
}
catch (WebException ex)
{
    var statusCode = ((HttpWebResponse)ex.Response).StatusCode;
    ...
}
```

If you want to determine the status code when the request is successful you'll need to [*monkey patch*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_patch) `WebClient`...

I actually reccomend that you use [*`HttpClient`*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient(v=vs.118).aspx) *instead* of `WebClient`. It is has a *much* nicer interface:

```
var client = new HttpClient();
HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("...").Result;
HttpStatusCode status = response.StatusCode;
string result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

Bare in mind that what you are describing is not a unit test but an [*integration test*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_testing) and it does not *seem* useful.